# BOOLEAN or TINYINT confusion

Tags: mysql, types, boolean, tinyint

I was designing a database for a site where I need to use a `boolean` datetype to store only 2 states, `true` or `false`. I am using `MySQL`.

While designing the database using `phpMyAdmin`, I found that I have both the `BOOLEAN` datatype and the `TINYINT` datatype. I went through different articles, some said `TINYINT` is the same as `BOOLEAN`, no difference. Some say `BOOLEAN` is converted into `TINYINT` in `MySQL`.

MY question is, if they both are same why do there exist two? There should be only one of them.

Here is the reference to the article(s) I read:

- [MySQL - Explain the difference between BOOL, TINYINT and BIT.](http://www.careerride.com/MySQL-BOOL-TINYINT-BIT.aspx)

Answer (score 148, accepted):

MySQL does not have internal boolean data type. It uses the smallest integer data type - TINYINT.

The BOOLEAN and BOOL are equivalents of TINYINT(1), because they are synonyms.

Try to create this table -

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  column1 BOOLEAN DEFAULT NULL
);
```

Then run SHOW CREATE TABLE, you will get this output -

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `column1` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

Comment: Yes, really. Haven't thought about the BIT.

Comment: But your answer is correct in all other aspects. What seems to be confusing the OP is the existence of synonyms.

Comment: It seems that it is done for backward compatibility. The BOOLEAN data type was before the MySQL 5 and the was not optimized BIT type, it was also TINYINT. From the documentation - New Features Planned for 5.1: Optimize the BIT type to take one bit. (BIT now takes one byte; it is treated as a synonym for TINYINT.).

Comment: Yes, you can know have `BIT(1)` or `BIT(17)` or even `BIT(64)`

Comment: @Devart  -- Where your answer has the most votes and appears first (in my list anyway) and some time has past, is there any chance you would be willing add to your answer to include some discussion of the BIT type on MySQL 5.1 and later?

Comment: Having MySQL 5.7 we see the same behavior - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-overview.html

Comment: @Jonathan Perhaps mentioning it is valuable, however BIT(1) doesn't actually use any less space than TINYINT(1) and does not display as most people would expect when using the standard mysql console. Because of that downside, and no storage benefit, just using TINYINT(1) or BOOLEAN seems to be the most common in my experience.

Answer (score 34):

Just a note for php developers (I lack the necessary stackoverflow points to post this as a comment) ... the automagic (and silent) conversion to TINYINT means that php retrieves a value from a "BOOLEAN" column as a "0" or "1", not the expected (by me) true/false.

A developer who is looking at the SQL used to create a table and sees something like:
"some_boolean BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE," might reasonably expect to see true/false results when a row containing that column is retrieved. Instead (at least in my version of PHP), the result will be "0" or "1" (yes, a string "0" or string "1", not an int 0/1, thank you php).

It's a nit, but enough to cause unit tests to fail.

Comment: As an additional note, PHP's mysql drivers pull in all integer types as strings.

Answer (score 24):

The Newest MySQL Versions have the new `BIT` data type in which you can specify the number of bits in the field, for example `BIT(1)` to use as `Boolean` type, because it can be only `0` or `1`.

Answer (score 7):

As of MySql 5.1 version [reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-type-overview.html)

```
BIT(M) =  approximately (M+7)/8 bytes, 
BIT(1) =  (1+7)/8 = 1 bytes (8 bits)
```

=========================================================================

```
TINYINT(1) take 8 bits.
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-numeric

Comment: Your reference says the storage required is actually "approximately (M+7)/8 bytes". i.e., it rounds up to the next full byte. Thus it does **not** take 1 bit.

Answer (score 6):

The numeric type overview for MySQL states:
BOOL, BOOLEAN:
These types are synonyms for TINYINT(1). A value of zero is considered false. Nonzero values are considered true.

See here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-overview.html