# Is it possible for a mysql query to return true/false instead of values?

Tags: mysql, boolean

I have a table:

```
custID    orderID    orderComponent
=====================================
1          123        pizza
1          123        wings
1          234        breadsticks
1          239        salad
2          456        pizza
2          890        salad
```

I have a list of values - pizza, wings, breadsticks, and salad. I need a way to just get a true/false value if a customer has at least one record containing each of these. Is that possible with a mysql query, or do I just have to do a `select distinct(orderComponent)` for each user and use php to check the results?

Comment: Given the data you have there, what would you want to be the result from your query?

Comment: I think `custID` 1 would return true and `custID` 2 would return false

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are just looking to see if the customer has ordered all items, then you can use:

```
select t1.custid,
  case when t2.total is not null 
    then 'true'
    else 'false'
  end OrderedAll
from yourtable t1
left join
(
  select custid, count(distinct orderComponent) Total
  from yourtable
  where orderComponent in ('pizza', 'wings', 'breadsticks', 'salad')
  group by custid
  having count(distinct orderComponent) = 4
) t2
  on t1.custid = t2.custid
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0782fd/8)

If you want to expand this out, to see if the `custid` has ordered all items in a single order, then you can use:

```
select t1.custid,
  t1.orderid,
  case when t2.total is not null 
    then 'true'
    else 'false'
  end OrderedAll
from yourtable t1
left join
(
  select custid, orderid, count(distinct orderComponent) Total
  from yourtable
  where orderComponent in ('pizza', 'wings', 'breadsticks', 'salad')
  group by custid, orderID
  having count(distinct orderComponent) = 4
) t2
  on t1.custid = t2.custid
  and t1.orderId = t2.orderid
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bbcf5/5)

If you only want the custid and the true/false value, then you can add `distinct` to the query.

```
select distinct t1.custid,
  case when t2.total is not null 
    then 'true'
    else 'false'
  end OrderedAll
from yourtable t1
left join
(
  select custid, count(distinct orderComponent) Total
  from yourtable
  where orderComponent in ('pizza', 'wings', 'breadsticks', 'salad')
  group by custid
  having count(distinct orderComponent) = 4
) t2
  on t1.custid = t2.custid
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0782fd/9)

Or by custid and orderid:

```
select distinct 
  t1.custid,
  t1.orderid,
  case when t2.total is not null 
    then 'true'
    else 'false'
  end OrderedAll
from yourtable t1
left join
(
  select custid, orderid, count(distinct orderComponent) Total
  from yourtable
  where orderComponent in ('pizza', 'wings', 'breadsticks', 'salad')
  group by custid, orderID
  having count(distinct orderComponent) = 4
) t2
  on t1.custid = t2.custid
  and t1.orderId = t2.orderid
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bbcf5/6)

Comment: So this query doesn't return a single true/false for a custID - it returns true/false for each row that has an order component in the list. Correct?

Comment: Yes it adds a true/false to each row. Do you only want the custid and true/false?

Comment: Yes. I need a single true/false per customer.

Comment: BTW, thanks for the links to the SQLFiddle. I use jsfiddle a lot, but had no idea there was one for SQL. Very useful.

Comment: Thanks. It's good to know how to do this; unfortunately because the list and number of items in the list can change frequently, it looks like it might be easier to do with PHP.

Comment: 'true' is a sting type. is it possible to return Boolean true ?

Comment: @muaaz possibly you'd have to try it

Comment: @bluefeet just tried following
`SELECT case when col1 = 1 
    then true
    else false
  end as result FROM myTable`
and there is an error. MySQL considers `true` as a column not a static value. it says unknown column

Comment: well, I found [the following](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167793/boolean-or-tinyint-confusion?answertab=votes#tab-top). So, **MySQL doesn't have Boolean data type**. really a strange thing.I didn't notice this before.

Answer (score 8):

```
select case when 
count(distinct orderComponent) = 4 
then 'true' 
else 'false' 
end as bool
from tbl
where custID=1
```

Comment: That won't work, because the list will not always be 4 items.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach.  This approach does not require an inline view (derived table), and can be effective if you want to include flags for multiple conditions:

### EDIT:

This returns `custID` that has a row for all four items:

```
SELECT t.custID
     , MAX(IF(t.orderComponent='breadsticks',1,0))
       + MAX(IF(t.orderComponent='pizza',1,0))
       + MAX(IF(t.orderComponent='salad',1,0))
       + MAX(IF(t.orderComponent='wings',1,0)) AS has_all_four
  FROM mytable t
 GROUP BY t.custID
HAVING has_all_four = 4
```

---

### ORIGINAL ANSWER:

(This checked for a customer "order" that had all four items, rather than just a "custID".)

```
SELECT t.custID
     , t.orderID
     , MAX(IF(t.orderComponent='breadsticks',1,0))
       + MAX(IF(t.orderComponent='pizza',1,0))
       + MAX(IF(t.orderComponent='salad',1,0))
       + MAX(IF(t.orderComponent='wings',1,0)) AS has_all_four
  -- , MAX(IF(t.orderComponent='breadsticks',1,0)) AS has_breadsticks
  -- , MAX(IF(t.orderComponent='pizza',1,0)) AS has_pizza
  -- , MAX(IF(t.orderComponent='salad',1,0)) AS has_salad
  -- , MAX(IF(t.orderComponent='wings',1,0)) AS has_wings
  FROM mytable t
 GROUP BY t.custID, t.orderID
HAVING has_all_four = 4
```

That will get the "orders" that have all four items.  If you want to return just values for custID, then use the query above as an inline view (wrap it in another query)

```
SELECT s.custID
  FROM (
         SELECT t.custID
              , t.orderID
              , MAX(IF(t.orderComponent='breadsticks',1,0))
                + MAX(IF(t.orderComponent='pizza',1,0))
                + MAX(IF(t.orderComponent='salad',1,0))
                + MAX(IF(t.orderComponent='wings',1,0)) AS has_all_four
             FROM mytable t
            GROUP BY t.custID, t.orderID
           HAVING has_all_four = 4
       ) s
 GROUP BY s.custID
```

Comment: @EmmyS. That's my bad. That query checks for an "order" containing all four items. To check for a customer, just omit the orderID from the GROUP BY and the SELECT list. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

@EmmyS: you can do it both ways. 
If you want to check using MySql use:

```
SELECT @rowcount:=COUNT(*) FROM orderComponent Where (Your Conditions);
IF (@rowcount > 0) THEN
    'True'
ELSE
    'False'
END IF
```