# MYSQL - INNER JOIN two tables result TRUE or FALSE

Tags: mysql

I have a below query that returns a result.
How can query the result which if there is result, return True, and if there is no result, return FALSE??

```
SELECT a.id 
FROM table1 AS a 
INNER JOIN table2 AS c
   ON (a.id=c.user_id AND a.id=4 AND c.complete_date is NULL AND c.st_number= 8)
```

Comment: I think you will find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342535/is-it-possible-for-a-mysql-query-to-return-true-false-instead-of-values). Possible duplicate

Comment: @chized: indeed possible duplicatie, but solution from Tim B. below is much better 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `EXISTS` here:

```sql
SELECT EXISTS (
    SELECT a.id
    FROM table1 AS a
    INNER JOIN table2 AS c ON a.id = c.user_id
    WHERE a.id = 4 AND c.complete_date IS NULL AND c.st_number = 8
);
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, worked perfect.

I was keep trying SELECT EXISTS but it didn't work for me. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Please don't merge inner join and where condition

```
SELECT a.id FROM table1 AS a 
INNER JOIN table2 AS c ON a.id=c.user_id 
where a.id=4 AND c.complete_date is NULL AND c.st_number= 8
```

Comment: This will return a list of values (the values from `a.id`)  How can this be "return True, and if there is no result, return FALSE"  ?