# Laravel migration boolean field created in Db like tiny integer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-migrations

I wrote a migration in Laravel:

```
 Schema::create('test', function (Blueprint $table) {
        //
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('city','30')->unique();
        $table->string('car','30')->unique();
        $table->boolean('required');
        $table->string('street','100')->nullable();
        $table->json('files');
        $table->timestamp('created_at');
    });
```

the field required is defined as boolean but in the db (MySql) is created as tinyint. How is it possible?

Comment: You can visit below link for more clarity: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167793/boolean-or-tinyint-confusion

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Tinyint is the same as `boolean`. `Tinyint` is an integer of size equal to 1 octet. When creating the column set as `boolean` the the db creates it as a tinyint with a size of `1 bit`. Thus making it's possible values `0`and `1` which is a `boolean`.

---

**From MySQL documentation**

```
BOOL, BOOLEAN
```

These types are synonyms for `TINYINT(1)`. A value of `zero` is considered `false`. Nonzero values are considered `true`

[Numeric Type Overview](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-overview.html)

Comment: This question is not related to mysql. It is related to laravel migration

Comment: Also there is problem that TINYINT(1) doesn't have a size of `1 bit` but `1 byte`! Only `BIT(1)` have really size of a `1 bit`

Comment: Isn't it not even 1 byte? But something like "in case you export it to a mainframe compatible format, this will be printed as 1 character". E.g. trimmed to the last decimal character: 0 to 9. You won't see that during normal queries.