# how to check if a column has truthy value using laravel's eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Suppose I have `Post` model that has `is_verified` column with `smallint` datatype, how can I get all records that is verified? One thing to do this is using this:

```php
Post::where('is_verified', true)->get();
```

The code above will produce the following query:

```sql
select * from `posts` where `posts`.`is_verified` = true
```

... which will get me all verified `Post` records; in note that `is_verified` on all existing records is either `0` or `1`.

However, after I get myself curious and try to manually change some `is_verified`'s record value from `1` to another truthy number e.g. `2`, the above eloquent query didn't work as expected anymore: records with `is_verified` value of `2` didn't get retrieved.

I tried to execute the sql query directly from HeidiSQL as well, but it was just the same. Then I tried to change the `=` in the sql query to `is`, and now it's working as expected i.e. all records with truthy `is_verified` get retrieved:

```sql
select * from `posts` where `posts`.`is_verified` is true
```

So my questions are:

- Does the above behaviour is correct and expected?
- How can I execute the last sql query in eloquent? One thing I can think of is `where('is_verified', '!=', 0)` but that feels weird in terms of readability especially when the query is pretty long and a bit complicated
- As I stated before, the `is_verified` column is a `smallint`. Does this affects the behaviour? Because this conversation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44028862) states that `boolean` column datatype is typically `tinyint`, not `smallint`.

And that's it. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some deeper digging, I would like to write down the things I've found:

- I have updated my mysql to the newest version as of now (v8) and `boolean` datatype defined in migration results in `tinyint(1)` in the db. This is happening turns out because in mysql `bool` or `boolean` are actually just the synonyms of `tinyint(1)`, so that was a totally normal behaviour, not due to lower-version issues.
- I found @dz0nika answer that states that `smallint` and `tinyint` results in different behaviour in the query to be quite incorrect. The two datatypes simply differ in terms of byte-size while storing integer value.
- As of mysql documentation, it is stated that:

  > A value of zero is considered false. Nonzero values are considered true.

  But also that:

  > However, the values TRUE and FALSE are merely aliases for 1 and 0, respectively.

  Meaning that:

  ```sql
  select * from `posts` where `posts`.`is_verified` = true;
  ```

  Is the same as

  ```sql
  select * from `posts` where `posts`.`is_verified` = 1;
  ```

  Thus the query will only get `Post` records with `is_verified` value of `1`.

  To get `Post` records with truthy `is_verified` value, wether `1`, or `2`, or `3`, etc; use `is` instead of `=` in the query:

  ```sql
  select * from `posts` where `posts`.`is_verified` is true;
  ```

You can read more about these informations [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and [here (look for the "boolean" part)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-syntax.html)

---

So, how about the eloquent query? How can we get `Post` with truthy `is_verified` using eloquent?

I still don't know what's best. But instead of using `where('is_verified', '!=', 0)` as I stated in my question, I believe it's better to use `whereRaw()` instead:

```php
Post::whereRaw('posts.is_verified is true')->get();
```

If you found this information to be quite missing or incorrect, please kindly reply. Your opinion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is not the correct way to handle boolean values, you shouldn't save boolean columns as `smallint`, you can use the explicit boolean column type as described [in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#column-method-boolean).
2. Once you setup the boolean field correctly the logic you have in place will work. So `Post::where('is_verified', true)->get();` will return the expected results.
3. Yes, the problem is the `smallint` column type, if you put `tinyint` it also should work like the boolean column. You can read more about the [differences here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: I just tried to make a new migration which add a new column with datatype of `boolean` as stated in the doc. However in my db, the new created column has `tinyint` with length of 1 instead. Is this because my mysql version? Would you kindly try to create one to see what datatype would it has? I also tried the same test and the behaviour is the exact same as explained in the question.

Comment: I once create a `json` datatype column from migration and get the exact datatype in the db locally. But when I deployed it live, what I get is `longtext` instead. This is because my server has older mysql version. So I'm wondering if the same thing is happening.

Comment: That is it rifqy, it definitely the mysql version you are running.

Comment: I've tried to update my mysql to v8 but keep getting the same behaviour. After some digging, I find your statements quite incorrect. I have posted my own answer explaining what I have found. Please kindly see it and leave your thoughts if possible.