# convert tinyint into boolean for later use with php json_encode

Tags: php, mysql, json

i have a table field that's type is `tinyint`. so the values in mysql can be stored as `1` for `true` and `0` for `false`.

i used php's mysqli module to fetch the data.
e.g.

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table_x_y");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc()
```

now i get a data row of the table. but the fields with the type `tinyint` are integers not boolean. 
the problem come with php's `json_encode`. i want to create a JSON object. But the boolean fields are still integer (in `$row`) and the encode function treated them as integer not as a boolean.

the result of the json object looks like

```
[
  {
    "foo": 1,
    "bar": 2
  },
  {
    "foo": 0,
    "bar": 1
  }
]
```

but i should look like

```
[
  {
    "foo": true,
    "bar": 2
  },
  {
    "foo": false,
    "bar": 1
  }
]
```

**Info**
`foo` datatype is `tinyint`.
`bar` datatype is `int`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which MySQL data type to use for storing boolean values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289727/which-mysql-data-type-to-use-for-storing-boolean-values)

Comment: Why should it interpret `tinyint` as a boolean? You'll need to convert those manually.

Comment: because boolean types are synonyms for TINYINT(1)

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly typecast `$row['foo']` to boolean while creating the dynamic array, kind of like this:

```
$array = array();
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table_x_y");
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $array[] = array('foo' => (bool)$row['foo'], 'bar' => $row['bar']);
}
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: so there is no way to configure mysql to cast tinyint into boolean while fetching the data?

Comment: all thread i read, said that tinyint and boolean are synonyms https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167793/boolean-or-tinyint-confusion?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @JuKe Let me rephrase my point, from **PHP's perspective** it doesn't automatically convert any binary value(`0` or `1`) to `TRUE` or `FALSE` i.e they are not interchangeably interpreted, unless you explicitly specify it using typecasting.